# JAR the generated files from a WSDL ( after wsdl2code )

Tags: maven-2, jar, wsdl2code

Our project consumes multiple Web Services

We have a project in which we would have a axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin or any similar plugin and perform the wsdl2code part

Our requirement is that we have to jar the generated files for a WSDL ( after wsdl2code )  and deploy it into a local remote repository . Other projects would consume the jar from the repository.
The same would happen for multiple WSDL's.

Is there any way to jar the generated files along with wsdl2code plugins and do the same for multiple wsdl's ?

The deploy part need not be in the pom.xml and can be handled with scripts

Thanks in Advance